# How do you style a master page in FreshMvvm MasterDetailContainer

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

Is there a way to apply styling to the menu in the Master of FreshMvvm MasterDetailNavigationContainer. A simple styling could be a background color or changing the font of the menu items. I Can see the menu is just a simple ContentPage with a ListView, but no hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a graveyard dig, but just hit the same issue.

Ended up working around it by creating my own container i.e. [copying the code](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/master/src/FreshMvvm/NavigationContainers/FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer.cs) ;-) and exposed `_menuPage` as a public property.